# using saveCanvas to save to a directory

Tags: processing, p5.js

I want p5js to save my canvas images to a directory:

```
saveCanvas(c, `kinect/kinect${i}`, 'jpg');
```

currently they just save to the desktop, and the file is renamed

```
kinect_kinect1.jpg etc...
```

How do I save to a directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the browser you use, but most should provide a preference/setting to allow you to set a different Downloads folder or allow you to select a separate download folder for each download.

If you plan to save more than 15 frames you should try [ccapture.js](https://github.com/spite/ccapture.js/)  (as [`saveFrames()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/saveFrames) doesn't capture more than that currently).

If you need more control than that remember you can always integrate [p5.js with node.js](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/p5.js,-node.js,-socket.io) and/or [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) to pass the canvas data and write to disk directly.

It really depends on what makes sense to use for your current project scope.